# Why is my AVR ATmega32 assembly code for keypad functionality not working

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega32

Firstly, I am extremely sorry if I donot know how to pose a question correctly. It's my first time using this forum for guidance!
I have to convert a 4x4 keypad matrix AVR assembly code into 4x3 and this has to be done via interrupts. So far, this is what i have done:

```
.INCLUDE  "M32DEF.INC"

.org  0x00
jmp main

.org 0x50
main:

.EQU  KEY_PORT  =  PORTC
.EQU  KEY_PIN  =  PINC
.EQU  KEY_DDR  =  DDRC

.EQU  LCD_DPRT  =  PORTA
.EQU  LCD_DDDR  =  DDRA
.EQU  LCD_DPIN  =  PINA
.EQU  LCD_CPRT  =  PORTB
.EQU  LCD_CDDR  =  DDRB
.EQU  LCD_CPIN  =  PINB
.EQU  LCD_RS  =  0
.EQU  LCD_RW  =  1
.EQU  LCD_EN  =  2


LDI  R20,  HIGH  (RAMEND) 
OUT  SPH,R20
LDI  R20,  LOW  (RAMEND) 
OUT  SPL,R20
;  ascii  code  for  keypressed  displayed  on  PORTD 
LDI  R21,  0xFF
OUT  DDRA,R21  ; port a output to lcd
;  PC0  – PC3  rows
;  PC4  – PC6  columns
LDI  R20,  0xF0  //portc  0-3  input  pins 
OUT  KEY_DDR,  R20

GroundAllColumns:
LDI  R20,  0b00001110  //  portc  0-3  display  111 
OUT  KEY_PORT,  R20

LDI  R21,0xFF;
OUT  LCD_DDDR,  R21  ;LCD  data  port  is  output 
OUT  LCD_CDDR,  R21 ;  A,B  PORT  AS  OUTPUT 
CBI  LCD_CPRT,LCD_EN
CALL  DELAY_2ms  ;wait  for  power  on 
LDI  R16,0x38  ;  FOR  7X5  DISPLAY
CALL  CMNDWRT  ;call  command  function 
CALL  DELAY_2ms  ;wait  2  ms
LDI  R16,0x0E  ;display  on,  cursor  on 
CALL  CMNDWRT  ;call  command  function 
LDI  R16,0x01  ;clear  LCD
CALL CMNDWRT 
CALL DELAY_2ms
LDI  R16,0x06  ;  INCREMENT  CURSOR 
CALL CMNDWRT
LDI  R16,0x84  ;  INCREMENT  CURSOR  IST  LINE  4TH  COLUMN 
CALL CMNDWRT

LDI  R16,  'F' 
CALL DATAWRT 
LDI  R16,  'A' 
CALL DATAWRT

LDI  R16,  'S' 
CALL DATAWRT 
LDI  R16,  'T' 
CALL DATAWRT

LDI  R16,0xC3  ;  INCREMENT  CURSOR  2ND  LINE  3RD  COLUMN 
CALL CMNDWRT
LDI  R16,  '0' 
CALL DATAWRT

here: rjmp here

KPD_ISR:
LDI  R21,  0b01111111 
OUT  KEY_PORT,R21 
NOP
IN  R21,KEY_PIN

ANDI  R21,0x0F 
CPI  R21,0x0F 
BRNE COL1

LDI  R21,  0b10111111 
OUT  KEY_PORT,  R21 
NOP
IN  R21,  KEY_PIN 
ANDI  R21,0x0F 
CPI  R21,0x0F 
BRNE COL2

LDI  R21,  0b11011111 
OUT  KEY_PORT,  R21 
NOP
IN  R21,  KEY_PIN 
ANDI  R21,0x0F 
CPI  R21,0x0F 
BRNE COL3

COL1:
LDI  R30,  LOW(KCODE0<<1) 
LDI  R31,  HIGH(KCODE0<<1)
RJMP  Find 
COL2:
LDI  R30,  LOW(KCODE1<<1) 
LDI  R31,  HIGH(KCODE1<<1)
RJMP  Find 
COL3:
LDI  R30,  LOW(KCODE2<<1) 
LDI  R31,  HIGH(KCODE2<<1)
RJMP  Find 

Find:
LSR R21
BRCC  Match 
LPM  R20,  Z+
RJMP  Find MATCH:
LPM  R20,  Z

ldi  r17,0x0f 
in  r16,pinc 
andi  r16,0x0f 
cp  r16,r17 
breq  kpd_isr

OUT  PORTA,  R20
mov  r16,r20
call  datawrt  ;  here call  BDELAY

rjmp  KPD_ISR


.ORG  0x300
KCODE0: .DB  '7',  '8',  '9' ;col1
KCODE1: .DB  '4',  '5',  '6'
KCODE2: .DB  '1',  '2',  '3'
KCODE3: .DB  'c',  '0',  '='
```

I get my initialized output on the LCD in my proteus simulation, but whenever I press anything on the keypad it doesn't register on the LCD. I can see from my simulation that my columns from pins p4-p6 are set which im not sure should be the case:
[My proteus simulation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZZqc.png)

I adjusted the code provided in my manual, but as I am learning I'm not sure at all where I went wrong. Also, i remember that interrupt service routines require a vector table (IVT) and you call them from their designated memory locations in the IVT. In the code I was provided, there was an ISR for the keypad button pressing but no IVT set. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Maybe first sort out if your LCD (whatever brand) is not working as expected, or of it's the keypad.  Also proper indentation of the code might help.

Comment: oh no i did verify if the LCD and keypad are faulty or not. They work just fine for other projects.

Comment: So when the code for the LCD is workng, and the code for the keypad is working, what's the question?

Comment: oh you meant the code, i thought you were referring to the hardware. no the code isn't working but the LCD and keypad themselves work fine with other projects.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not contain any ISR function. The ISR function is activated by an interrupt. You don't have any interrupt enabled and you don't have a jump set to the relevant ISR function.

`KPD_ISR` is not an ISR, and is not a function. The function is called by the `CALL` instruction and must end with the RET instruction. The ISR function is called by an interrupt and must end with an `RETI` instruction. In order for the activated interrupt to call the ISR function, there must be a jump to the ISR at the appropriate place in the IVT.

And one more important thing. The ISR must not cause any change to the state of the processor after completion. So it has to take care of saving and restoring all used registers including SREG.

For the next ISR, it should be as short as possible. In no case should it contain a long-lasting code, writing on the display in your code.

Please read some tutorial, for example [here](http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/interrupts/index.html)

Comment: I tried finding the correct ISR but so far I've had zero luck. Or maybe, there is no ISR for keypad inputs and i have to somehow send the keypad signal to int0 or int1? I'm so confused about how to set up interrupts for keypads at the moment lol. if there's a specific example relating to peripherals like keypads i could look at in assembly code then id maybe get it cleared.

Comment: It's up to you how you plan to have it connected. If you don't know how to connect it, we can't advise how to operate it programmatically. There are basically two ways. One is to enable an interrupt via an external pin(s). The second way is to use a timer at regular intervals to start the interrupt handler and perform a keyboard scan there. Then signal events such as a key press or release or both to the main program. I usually use the second method because it's easy to deal with the debounce buttons. Study the basic principles of individual options and test their understanding.